# Binary to Decimal Applet with radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, unicode, applet, char

I'm trying to make an applet that converts binary to decimal and decimal to binary.  I have already written applets that do each individual but now I want to make one which uses radio buttons to select the conversion the user wants to do and then have the convert button carry out that conversion.  I am stuck at the moment and not quite sure where to go from here...  It doesn't currently compile.

I also want to include an arrow that points either up or down depending on the radio button selected... I've tried to implement the Unicode for said arrow into a JLabel but they do not accept characters, how would one go about this?

Thank you very much any help is greatly appreciated.

Heres my current mess of code...

EDIT:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class binaryAndDecimalConvert extends JApplet
{
    private JPanel bPanel;
    private JPanel dPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel radioPanel;
    private JPanel arrowPanel;

    private JLabel arrowUp;
    private JLabel arrowDown;

    private JTextField binaryTxt;
    private JTextField decimalTxt;

    private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
    private JRadioButton binaryConvButton;
    private JRadioButton decimalConvButton;

    public void init()
    {
        Font font = new Font("display font", Font.BOLD, 15);



        //build the panels
        buildBpanel();
        buildArrowPanel();
        buildDpanel();
        buildButtonPanel();
        buildRadioPanel();



        //create Layout Manager.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        // Add the panels to the content pan.
        add(bPanel);
        add(arrowPanel);
        add(dPanel);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(radioPanel);
    }


    private void buildDpanel()
    {
        dPanel = new JPanel();
        dPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
        JLabel message2 = new JLabel("Decimal Number: ");

        decimalTxt = new JTextField(15);

        dPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        dPanel.add(message2);
        dPanel.add(decimalTxt);
    }



    private void buildBpanel()
    {
        //create the panel
        bPanel = new JPanel();
        bPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
        //create a label to display a mssage
        JLabel message1 = new JLabel("Binary Number: ");

        //create a text field for the binary number
        binaryTxt = new JTextField(15);


        //create a layout manager for the panel
        bPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        ///add the label and text field to the panel
        bPanel.add(message1);
        bPanel.add(binaryTxt);
    }

    public void buildRadioPanel()
    {
        radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);

        binaryConvButton = new JRadioButton("Binary to Decimal");
        decimalConvButton = new JRadioButton("Decimal to Binary");

        radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioButtonGroup.add(binaryConvButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(decimalConvButton);

        binaryConvButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        decimalConvButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

        binaryConvButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        decimalConvButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

        radioPanel.add(binaryConvButton);
        radioPanel.add(decimalConvButton);

        binaryConvButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void buildArrowPanel()
    {
        arrowPanel = new JPanel();

        arrowUp = new JLabel("\u2191");
        arrowDown = new JLabel("\u2193");

        arrowPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);

        arrowPanel.add(arrowDown);

    }

    private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == binaryConvButton)
            {
                arrowPanel.add(arrowUp);
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == decimalConvButton)
                arrowPanel.add(arrowDown);




        }
    }



    private void buildButtonPanel()
    {
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
        JButton convButton = new JButton("Convert");

        convButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        buttonPanel.add(convButton);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //binary to decimal conversion
            String decimalNum= "";
            int decimal1 = 0;
            String binaryNum = "";
            int power = 1;
            int dec;

            if(e.getSource() == decimalConvButton)
            {
            binaryNum=binaryTxt.getText();
            for(int i = 1; i <= binaryNum.length(); i++)
            {
                if(binaryNum.charAt(binaryNum.length()-i) == '1')
                {
                    decimal1 = (decimal1 + power);
                }
            power = (power*2);
            }
            decimalNum = Integer.toString(decimal1);
            decimalTxt.setText(decimalNum);
            }

            //decimal to binary
            if(e.getSource() == binaryConvButton)
            {
                  dec = Integer.parseInt(decimalTxt.getText());
                  while (dec != 0)
                  {
                        binaryNum = (dec % 2) + binaryNum;
                        dec /= 2;
                  }
                binaryTxt.setText(binaryNum);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us why or how it doesn't compile. Any and all error messages are important. Also it's great that you want to include this or that in your code, but you'll need to show us your attempts to achieve this.

Comment: I attempted to make a character like
    char upArrow = '\u2191';
    char downArrow = '\2193';
and then add them to a JLabel which i would add to one of the panels or make another panel for it if needed.  Although, i found out that i can not add a character or even a string to a JLabel.  Other than that I don't know what to try :(.

Comment: You need to use a String not a char, so it's `"\u2191"`, not `'\u2191'`

Answer (score 2):

One problem you've got is that you are re-declaring a class field inside of a method and effectively "shadowing" the field making it invisible. That field is "binary"

Here's where you initially declare it:

```
public class BinaryAndDecimalConvert extends JApplet {
   private JPanel bPanel;

   //...

   private JTextField binary;
```

Here's where you shadow it:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String decimalNum = "";
     int decimal1 = 0;
     String binaryNum = "";
     int power = 1;

     String binary;  // **** redeclared here ****

     if (binaryToDec = true) {

        binaryNum = binary.getText(); // so this won't work
```

Solution: don't give variables local to a method the same name as important class fields.

Next, you try to call `setText()` on a String variable, binaryNumber:

```
binaryNumber.setText(decimal1);
```

String doesn't have such a method, so get rid of this method call.

Comment: I updated my code, it now goes from binary to decimal but im still having trouble getting it to go properly from decimal to binary.  I'm also still lost on how to show the unicode arrow.

Thankyou

Comment: Edited code once more and updated original post to reflect the changes... I found regardless of the radio button i press the binary to decimal conversion always works were as my decimal to binary never works, i don't quite understand why.  Could you recommend another way of coding my RadioButtonListener possibly?

Thankyou!

Comment: I would use a debugger to find out why my code isn't working. Either that or sprinkle println statements in key locations in my code to help me figure this out.

Comment: I'll continue to do that thank you, do you think that the Boolean variable that the radio buttons set is a good idea?   I feel as if that is where i'm going wrong

Comment: No, I'd perhaps use the radiobutton's actionlistener to set the arrow jlabel, but I'd just have the JButton's ActionListener check to see which JRadioButton is selected rather than use a boolean.

Comment: I updated my code once more, i can now display the arrows, but it seems as if my radio buttons have no effect on the program what so ever... am I missing something here?  Thank you for all your help thus far but i feel as if i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I've finished the program, for those wondering I created two strings that held the unicode for each arrow, i then created a panel and a JLabel and used (variable).setText() in order to switch between the two arrows depending upon which radio button was selected.  I will update the main post soon.